# Cloning/downloading files via a python script

Tags: python, scripting

I was wondering how to clone/download a github file or files via a python script. I cant seem to figure out how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Maurice Meyer's method, you can do as follows:

In order to clone an entire git repository, you would use the following command line script:

`git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY`

Taking that into account, you could have a python script which would execute this command, by using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library, such as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["git", "clone", "https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY"])
```